# write a vba excel function not knowing parameter is string or dictionary

Tags: excel, vba, function, parameters, parameter-passing

How do i **write a function in excel vba** that is something like this in php?

```
public function name($data) {

  if ($data==="*") {
    return "*";
  }

  if (isset($data[0])) {
    return $data[0];
  }
}
```

The biggest issue is that i need to define the data type in the function for my parameter

I am expecting either a string or a dictionary that has a key called "0"

Answer (score 3):

A `0` in dictionary doesn't hold any value. A `1` perhaps can give you the desired result. I don't know php but whatever I could understand from the above code and your requirement, this is what I came up with so I am not sure if this is what you want?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim Dict1 As Dictionary
    Dim sString As String

    Set Dict1 = New Dictionary

    With Dict1
      .CompareMode = BinaryCompare
      .Add 1, "Item 1"
    End With

    sString = "Sid"

    Debug.Print sName(Dict1)
    Debug.Print sName(sString)
End Sub

Public Function sName(Inpt As Variant) As Variant
    If TypeName(Inpt) = "Dictionary" Then
        sName = Inpt.Item(1)
    ElseIf TypeName(Inpt) = "String" Then
        sName = Inpt
    End If
End Function
```

**EDIT**

If you still want to use `0`, then while adding to the dictionary, use a `0` for example

```
    With Dict1
      .CompareMode = BinaryCompare
      .Add 0, "Item 1"
    End With
```

and then you can use a `0` in the function as below

```
sName = Inpt.Item(0)
```

**SNAPSHOT (ALL 3 CONDITIONS - USE OF 0 AND 1)**

[image]

HTH

Sid

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I will mark this as right once I confirm it

Comment: as far as i understand dictionary keys are always text. so in the code example above i think you would have to use `"1" or "0"`. it is also usually a good idea to check for the keys existence with `.exists`

Comment: @Pynner: Yes you are absolutely correct on `.exists`. I deliberately didn't use `.Exist` so that I can demonstrate the use of `0` as in CASE 2 above :) If you notice in CASE 2, the use of `.(0)` instead of `.(1)` gives a null value instead of an error. :)

Comment: @siddarth rout thanks, a couple of new tricks for me in that function.